# CASE statement to be used on date field

Tags: t-sql

I have a column adetdate which has date in the format '2015-05-01 00:00:00.000'

is it possible to write a case statement like

```
case adetdate
adetdate  between '2015-05-01 00:00:00.000' and '2015-05-01 23:59:59.999' then print  'MAY 1st' 
adetdate  between '2015-05-02 00:00:00.000' and '2015-05-02 23:59:59.999' print  'MAY 2nd'
```

Comment: This is incorrect syntax of `CASE` at all.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server? Might be that `FORMAT()` is what you are looking for...

Comment: Worth pointing out that SQL doesn't have a case statement, it has a case expression.  Statements control flow, while expressions return a value.  [This is a link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) to the Microsoft docs, which include working examples.

Answer (score 1):

If correctly understood. You could convert your `DATETIME` column to `DATE` in this case time will be ignored. Something like:

```
PRINT CASE CAST(adetdate AS DATE)
         WHEN '2015-05-01' THEN 'MAY 1'
         WHEN '2015-05-02' THEN 'MAY 2'
         --........
      END AS Something
```

---

Another, more dynamic way is to use `CONVERT` in following:

```
declare @datetime datetime = '2015-05-01 00:00:00.000'

select upper(convert(varchar(6), @datetime, 7))
```

**OUTPUT**

Will be in following format:

```
MAY 01
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a generic approach like this:

```
SET LANGUAGE English
DECLARE @d DATETIME=GETDATE();
SELECT FORMAT(@d,'MMM d') + CASE DAY(@d)
                          WHEN 1 THEN 'st'
                          WHEN 2 THEN 'nd'
                          WHEN 3 THEN 'rd'
                          ELSE 'th' END
```

If you are using a SQL Server <2012 you might find this helpful:

```
DECLARE @d DATETIME=GETDATE();
SELECT UPPER(DATENAME(MONTH,@d)) + ' ' + CAST(DAY(@d) AS VARCHAR(2))
       + CASE DAY(@d)
         WHEN 1 THEN 'st'
         WHEN 2 THEN 'nd'
         WHEN 3 THEN 'rd'
         ELSE 'th' END
```